# Accessing owners field from applications graph api call

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to iterate through the owners in the graph api response but nothing comes. In a cs file I have this call bellow:

```
var owners = await graphServiceClient.Applications["MyId"].Owners.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select =
        ["id", "displayName", "givenName"];
});

var owner = (Microsoft.Graph.Models.User)owners.Value[0];

//I can get the Id of said owner
_logger.LogInformation($"Result for users {owners.Value[0].Id}");

//But non of the of the following seem to display anything. It displays the log and the values either empty or null
_logger.LogInformation($"Result for users {owners.Value[0].DisplayName}");
_logger.LogInformation($"Result for owner name {owner.DisplayName}");
```

What am I doing wrong in trying to access the display name field? In the Developer Graph website, GUI, or whatever it is called I can see there's at least one owner for said application. Just not understanding on why I can't iterate or access said field. TIA.

Comment: Do you use delegated or application permissions? It looks like you are missing permissions for reading users details like User.ReadBasic.All or User.Read.All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one app registration named **`SriApp`** with below users as Owners:

[image]

Make sure to assign *Application.Read.All* and *User.Read.All* permissions of **Application** type while using service principal authentication.

[image]

In my case, I used below sample code to list application owners with their display names and got **response** successfully like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        var clientId = "appId";
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";

        var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            var owners = await graphServiceClient.Applications["appObjId"].Owners.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "displayName", "givenName" };
            });

            foreach (var owner in owners.Value)
            {
                var user = (User)owner;
                Console.WriteLine($"Id: {user.Id}, Display Name: {user.DisplayName}, Given Name: {user.GivenName}");
            }

        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

If you are using delegated flows, you need to assign *Application.Read.All* and *User.Read.All* permissions of **Delegated** type.

**Reference:**
[List owners - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions)

Comment: I don't agree. The doc says that the response object shown here might be shortened for readability. The example shows only id, but if you try the request https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}/owners?$select=id,displayName,givenName in Graph Explorer, it will return displayName and givenName